# Protecting website from Clickjacking; What should be the expected behavior?

Tags: html, security, iframe, clickjacking

Is it acceptable solution to have clickjacking website redirect to your website?(so when you bust out of the frame you are now showing your website)
Let us say you see click here to win ipad clickjacking webpage. But when you visit that website immediately in 2 seconds you are taken to the website that the original website the hackers wanted  you to clickjack. So now you do not see the iframe and click here ipad webpage. Which one is better(more secure) Busting out of iframe and redirect to your website or stay on free ipad page and not showing your website on the iframe?

Comment: I wish I understood what you are asking. Does not sound very clean to me

Comment: If you see a link "Click here to win an iPad" you won't win an iPad anyway, so why click at all.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `X-Frame-Options: DENY` header to your response and let HTTP handle it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 0):

### **Defending with X-Frame-Options Response Headers**

---

The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame> or <iframe>`. Sites can use this to avoid Clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites. Set the X-Frame-Options header for all responses containing HTML content. The possible values are "`DENY`", "`SAMEORIGIN`", or "`ALLOW-FROM uri`"

***X-Frame-Options Header Types***

There are three possible values for the X-Frame-Options header:

`DENY`, which prevents any domain from framing the content. The "`DENY`" setting is recommended unless a specific need has been identified for framing.
SAMEORIGIN, which only allows the current site to frame the content.
`ALLOW-FROM uri`, which permits the specified '`uri`' to frame this page. (e.g., `ALLOW-FROM http://www.example.com`) Check Limitations Below this will fail open if the browser does not support it. Other browsers support the new CSP frame-ancestors directive instead. A few support both.

---

### **window.confirm() Protection**

---

The use of x-frame-options or a frame-breaking script is a more fail-safe method of clickjacking protection. However, in scenarios where content must be frameable, then a window.confirm() can be used to help mitigate Clickjacking by informing the user of the action they are about to perform.

Invoking `window.confirm()` will display a popup that cannot be framed. If the `window.confirm()` originates from within an iframe with a different domain than the parent, then the dialog box will display what domain the `window.confirm()` originated from. In this scenario the browser is displaying the origin of the dialog box to help mitigate Clickjacking attacks. It should be noted that Internet Explorer is the only known browser that does not display the domain that the window.confirm() dialog box originated from, to address this issue with Internet Explorer insure that the message within the dialog box contains contextual information about the type of action being performed. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var action_confirm = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete your youtube account?")
   if (action_confirm) {
       //... perform action
   } else {
       //...  The user does not want to perform the requested action.
   }
</script>
```